# jquery char counter plugin not working

Tags: jquery, counter

Here is the html and internal javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.jqEasyCharCounter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("textarea").click(function () {
   var code = $("textarea#statuspost").val();

if(code == "Fight for what's right with up to 210 bytes...")
{
     $("textarea").html("");
}

});

$('#statuspost').jqEasyCounter({
'maxChars': 210,
'maxCharsWarning': 200,
'msgFontSize': '16px',
'msgFontColor': '#d4d4d4',
'msgFontFamily': 'Verdana',
'msgTextAlign': 'left',
'msgWarningColor': 'red',
'msgAppendMethod': 'insertBefore'    
});

});
</script>


<div id="loop">
<form method="post" action="discussion-proof.php" name="myform">
 <textarea id="statuspost" name="status" cols="31" rows="6"/>
 Fight for what's right with up to 210 bytes...</textarea>

 <input type="text" id="tag" name="tag" onclick="clear_box()" value="Tag your post!" />
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Define "not working" if you want help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear all textareas use `$('textarea').val('');` instead of `$("textarea").html("");`
If you don't want to clear ALL textareas use your selector, e.g. `$('#statuspost').val('');`